# Integral $ \int_0^{\pi}\frac{dx}{a + \cos{x}} $

Tags: calculus, special-functions

> For $ a > 1 $ show that
>   \begin{equation}
> J = \int\limits_0^{\pi}\frac{dx}{a + \cos{x}}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{a^2 -1}}
> \end{equation}

---

Neither of trivial methods like integration by parts works. The most natural change of variable I see is 
\begin{equation}
t = \cos{x}\\
dt = d\cos{x}=-\sin x \, dx=-\sqrt{1 - t^2} \, dx \text{ for } x \in [0, \pi]   
\end{equation}
Therefore
\begin{equation}
J = \int\limits_{-1}^{1}\frac{dt}{(a + t)\sqrt{1 - t^2}}
\end{equation}
which seems relatively simple, but I didn't manage to either solve it by any common method or to find it in any list of integrals.

Comment: Try the Weirstrass substitution.

Comment: One way would be to use residue theory from complex analysis. In fact, this exact integral is given as an example in page 155 of "Complex Analysis" (3rd edition) by Ahlfors.

Comment: Added the tag special-functions due to applications from that subject, as I hope my answer shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Prism thank you. It's a great solution, let me share it.

Substitution $ z = e^{ix} $, than
\begin{equation}
\cos{x}=\frac{1}{2}(z + \frac{1}{z})\\
\sin{x}=\frac{1}{2i}(z - \frac{1}{z})\\
dx = -i\frac{dz}{z}
\end{equation}

Since $ \cos{x} $ takes the same values in the intervals $ (0, \pi) $ and $ (\pi, 2\pi) $ it is clear that the integral from $ 0 $ to $ \pi $ is one-half of the integral from $ 0 $ to $ 2\pi $. Taking this into account we find that the integral equals
\begin{equation}
-i\oint\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{z^2 + 2az + 1}
\end{equation}
The denominator can be factored into $ (z - \alpha)(z - \beta) $ with
\begin{equation}
\alpha = -a + \sqrt{a^2 - 1}, \ \beta = -a - \sqrt{a^2 - 1}
\end{equation}
Evidently $ |\alpha| < 1,\ |\beta| > 1 $, and the residue at $ \alpha $ is $ \frac{1}{(\alpha - \beta)} $. The value of the integral is found to be $\pi / \sqrt{a^2 - 1}$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $y = \tan\frac{x}{2}$, $\cos x = \cos^2\frac{x}{2} - \sin^2\frac{x}{2}$, then you will have a quadratic polynomial in the denominator

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on usage of the Legendre function the first kind.

For $s\in\mathbb{C}$ and $x>1$ the Legendre function of the first kind, $P_s(x)$, admits the [integral representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_function#Integral_representations) 
$$P_s(x) =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}\cos\theta\right)^s d\theta\tag{1}$$

Moreover, we have the relation $$P_{-s-1}=P_s\tag{2}$$

Using (1) and (2) one finds
\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{0}^{\pi}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}+\cos\theta\right)^s d\theta &=&\frac12\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}+\cos\theta\right)^s d\theta \\
&=&\frac{\pi P_s(x)}{(x^2-1)^{s/2}}=\frac{\pi P_{-s-1}(x)}{(x^2-1)^{s/2}}\end{eqnarray*}
Now,  $x>1$ and hence $x/\sqrt{x^2-1}>1$ too, and if we solve for $$a=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$ we get $$x=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}$$
and also $\sqrt{x^2-1}=1/\sqrt{a^2-1}$. 
Thus,
$$\int_0^{\pi}\left(a+\cos\theta\right)^s d\theta = \frac{\pi P_{-s-1}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}\right)}{(a^2-1)^{-s/2}}.$$

Now we put $s=-1$, then (since $P_0(x)=1$) (2) gives us 
$$P_{-1}(x)=1 $$ 
and we get
$$\int_0^\pi\frac{d\theta}{a+\cos\theta}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}$$

---

Note that the above method works well, i.e. leads to a explicit value, for all integer values $s$  - the reason is (2) together with the fact that Legendre functions with non-negative integer parameter reduces to [Legendre polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials), which are known from say [Rodrigues' formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_formula).

---

For completeness it should be mentioned that (2) can be proved by the change of variables $x+\sqrt{x^2-1}(2t-1)\mapsto 1/(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}(2u-1))$ in an other integral representation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_function#Integral_representations).